# What determines the versions of the spring boot dependencies when defined without a version in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

When defining such in build.gradle, how does spring boot knows which version to use? Is it based on the spring boot gradle plugin version?

```
dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

I may have missed this in the documentation, so please point me in the right direction if ever.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html: the documentation answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

here the table of all the default spring boot dependencies version

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html